# Error when compiling in the device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, path

I am getting the below error as "apple mach-o linker error xcode"

```
Ld "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Voice_-flsfylxijlgswbbqkqwjspmgcska/Build/Intermediates/Voice .build/Debug-iphoneos/Voice .build/Objects-normal/armv6/Voice " normal armv6
    cd "/Users/admin/Desktop/Voice "
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Voice_-flsfylxijlgswbbqkqwjspmgcska/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "-L/Users/admin/Desktop/Voice /../Common Files/src" -F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Voice_-flsfylxijlgswbbqkqwjspmgcska/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Voice_-flsfylxijlgswbbqkqwjspmgcska/Build/Intermediates/Voice .build/Debug-iphoneos/Voice .build/Objects-normal/armv6/Voice .LinkFileList" -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -framework AudioUnit -framework OpenAL -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreAudio -framework Accelerate -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lDIRAC_iOS4-fat -o "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Voice_-flsfylxijlgswbbqkqwjspmgcska/Build/Intermediates/Voice .build/Debug-iphoneos/Voice .build/Objects-normal/armv6/Voice "

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/admin/Desktop/Voice /../Common Files/src'
ld: framework not found AudioUnit
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Please help me,

I did not get any solution even I added Audio unit framework it displays same error.

Madan Mohan

Comment: Has it ever worked? If so, what did you change that stopped it working? If it has never worked, what are you trying to do? The error message is pretty self explanatory so more context would be useful please.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a clean and then setting up your frameworks again?

Comment: it's probably happening because you're including the same file twice or an object outside your class

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the audio unit framework and create "-L/Users/admin/Desktop/Voice /../Common Files/src" what are you doing with this dir?

Comment: Even I not solved the problem. I am working to change the recorded audio by pitch varies.